# How to determine which files the current user has read and execute permissions to, even when permissions are modified

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, permissions

I'm trying to create a shell script where the command lists all the **readable and executable** permitted files for me or the current user, whomever it may be and wherever the location of the user. So even if I change permissions in the future, the changes will still be reflected.

This is what I have so far:

```
user=`id -un`
group=`id -gn`

IFS='
'
for file in `ls -al /home/cg/root`; do
    perm=$(echo $file | awk '{print $1}')
    fileowner=$(echo $file | awk '{print $3}')
    filegroup=$(echo $file | awk '{print $4}')
    ownerreadbit=${perm:1:2}
    ownerexecbit=${perm:3:4}
    groupreadbit=${perm:4:5}
    groupexecbit=${perm:6:7}
    worldreadbit=${perm:7:8}
    worldexecbit=${perm:9:10}
    if ["$user"=="$fileowner" && "$ownerreadbit"=="r" && "$ownerexecbit"=="x"]; then
        echo $file
    elif ["$group"=="$filegroup" && "$groupreadbit"=="r" &&" $groupexecbit"=="x"]; then
        echo $file
    elif ["$worldreadbit"=="r" && "$worldexecbit"=="x"]; then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't use the GNU `find` command?

```
find /home/cg/root -readable -executable
```

or only list the files:

```
find /home/cg/root -readable -executable -type f
```

Comment: And `-writable` for writable files ;-).

Answer (score 0):

User IporSricer's answer `find /home/cg/root -readable -executable` is the way to go. Note also that the `find` command has an added advantage of being able to customize the format of its output, including options to include many possible details about each file. Refer to option `-printf` in the `man` page. The main purpose of this answer is to try to provide useful feedback for your question for your future scripts.

1. Don't use the output of `ls` for scripting! This is a common beginner mistake. ref [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)
2. Instead of using `ls`, just use the shell's native *file globbing*, eg. `/home/cg/root/*`. That's (one of the reasons) why the feature exists.
3. Your script doesn't descend into sub-directories, but user IporSricer's answer does.
4. You mis-use the substring expansion feature of the shell, so none of your tests whould work. The second parameter is a substring *length*, not am end position, so `${perm:1:2}` returns a two-character substring; you want `${perm:1:1}` for a single character substring.
5. A quicker test would be to define separate varaiables of the form `owner=${perm:1:2}` and then test them against "rx".
6. I'm surprised that you seem to say that `&&` works inside a `[` test command; I thought it should only work inside a `[[`.
7. Since all three of your `if`, `elif`, `elif` are doing the same thing, an `echo`, you could combine them into a single `if` by using the `||` logical 'or' operator (outside the `[` tests).

Hope that's useful.